# Python unicode popen or Popen error reading unicode

Tags: python, shell, unicode, popen

I have a program that generates the following output:

```
             ┌───────────────────────┐
             │10 day weather forecast│
             └───────────────────────┘
▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁
Tonight Sep 27      Clear               54      0 %
Tue Sep 28          Sunny               85/61   0 %
Wed Sep 29          Sunny               86/62   0 %
Thu Sep 30          Sunny               87/65   0 %
Fri Oct 01          Sunny               85/62   0 %
Sat Oct 02          Sunny               81/59   0 %
Sun Oct 03          Sunny               79/56   0 %
Mon Oct 04          Sunny               78/58   0 %
Tue Oct 05          Sunny               81/61   0 %
Wed Oct 06          Sunny               81/61   0 %

Last Updated Sep 27 10:20 p.m. CT
▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔
```

This doesn't seem to format right on this site, but the lower lines at the top and the upper lines at the bottom result in a unicode error.

Here is the code example for os.popen

```
>>> buffer = popen('10day', 'r').read()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/woodnt/python/10_day_forecast.py", line 129, in <module>
    line_lower(51)
  File "/home/woodnt/python/lib/box.py", line 24, in line_lower
    print upper_line * len
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-50: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> print buffer

             ┌───────────────────────┐
             │10 day weather forecast│
             └───────────────────────┘

>>>
```

Here is the same for subprocess.Popen:

```
f = Popen('10day', stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
o, er = f.communicate()
print o

             ┌───────────────────────┐
             │10 day weather forecast│
             └───────────────────────┘

print er
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/woodnt/python/10_day_forecast.py", line 129, in <module>
    line_lower(51)
  File "/home/woodnt/python/lib/box.py", line 24, in line_lower
    print upper_line * len
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-50: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Any ideas if this can be made to work without a lot of "under the hood" work? I'm just learning programming and starting with python

Comment: Don't know why formatting is so off on the above. My apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say running your program from the console should work correctly because Python can guess the console encoding of the terminal window (cp437 on US Windows), but when run through a pipe Python uses the default of ascii.  Try changing your program to `encode` all Unicode output to an explicit encoding, such as:

print (upper_line * len).encode('cp437')

Then when you read it from the pipe, you can either `decode` back to Unicode or print it directly to the terminal.

Comment: Sadly, it does balk at the console. From a python console, as soon as one excutes the popen. I think you are spot on about the pipe defaulting to ascii. Guess there is no way to change this behavior. Too bad. It is a good idea to do as you suggest. I will give it a go.

Comment: That so did the trick. Thank you for an excellent work-around idea. I guess if this were another program and I didn't have the source and it were a binary, there would be no way round this, eh?

Comment: When the source program is Python, you can use `os.environ['PYTHONIOENCODING'] = 'utf-8'` before the `Popen`.  This environment variable instructs python to use UTF-8 as the default instead of ASCII.  All Unicode characters can be sent with this encoding...just `.decode('utf-8')` the output received to turn in back to Unicode.