# python os.popen fails when given umlauted character

Tags: python, windows, popen

Under winxp (pro x64 version 2003, sp2), running the following at cmd prompt works fine:

```
dir C:\testüüüdirectory\
```

Please note the 'ü' character.

But from python 2.7.1.4, the following always returns an error code 1:

```
>>> res = os.popen("dir C:\\testüüüdirectory\\")
>>> res.close()
1
>>>
```

How can i get popen to accept the ü character?

Comment: Why are you using `os.popen` instead of [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html)?

Comment: What version of Python? What version of windows? I don't get `1` I get `255` and `res.closed` is `False` until I close it, and `res.errors` is `None`, directly copying that. What encoding did you declare in your Python source file?

Comment: winxp pro x64 2003 sp2, python 2.7.14. i'm doing this at the repl so i assume it's guessing the cmd terminals encoding.

Comment: @phihag subprocess.Popen doesn't work either

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810302/python-unicode-popen-or-popen-error-reading-unicode

Comment: [os.open](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.popen) "Deprecated since version 2.6: This function is obsolete. Use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module."  See [Replacing os.popen](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-popen-os-popen2-os-popen3).  Besides that, chown and eswald have nice answers about the encoding.

Comment: @chown: Related, but not really the same.  That question is talking about the output of the program, where this one is talking about finding the program in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would probably be an encoding issue, where your input doesn't quite match what the file system expects on output.  First, you'll need to tell Python what encoding your input uses, then what encoding the `popen()` call expects.

```
>>> filename = "C:\\testüüüdirectory\\".decode("utf-8")
>>> res = os.popen("dir " + filename.encode("cp1252"))
```

You may have to experiment with various encoding combinations to get the right pair.  UTF-8, UTF-16, and cp1252 are the most likely candidates for Windows, but your system might be set up to use [another encoding](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).  If you're really lucky, `os.popen()` might even accept a Unicode string, in which case the `encode()` step could be skipped.

If you're really unlucky, [character canonicalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonicalization#Unicode) could be an issue.  There are two possible representations of "ü" in Unicode: U+00FC or U+0075 U+0308; the second is a "u" with a combining diaresis, while the first is pre-combined.  If Windows expects one while `encode()` produces the other, you may have to work a bit to get the right string.

Comment: thanks. this makes me one sad panda though :( haven't been able to figure out the magic combination so far. might have more luck convincing my european clients to stop using their precious umlauts :D

Comment: Just remember that hard coding the enconding like that will make it OS dependant and become an issue if you have to run it on a different setup.

Comment: @DecioLira: Good point.  The `decode()` call is dependent only on the encoding of the file (or terminal, while at the interactive prompt), and could be replaced by `u""` with either a file-level encoding marker or `\u0000` escapes.  The `encode()` call should probably use `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` as chown suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with a `u` in front of the string:

```
 res = os.popen(u"dir C:\\testüüüdirectory\\")
```

[More on unicode strings / lexical analysis](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html)

Check [sys.getfilesystemencoding](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.getfilesystemencoding) also to make sure you can have  such file names.